# Progress bar turns back and forth issue

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, progress-bar

I'm working on a progress bar width changing on nav-links click. I've an issue when I click on every nav-link, progress-bar reach its width correctly, but it also turns back and forth, I don't understand why it happens.
Below I post the code:

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.5.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-TX8t27EcRE3e/ihU7zmQxVncDAy5uIKz4rEkgIXeMed4M0jlfIDPvg6uqKI2xXr2" crossorigin="anonymous">

<!-- Nav tabs -->
<ul class="nav nav-tabs" id="myTab" role="tablist">
  <li class="nav-item" role="presentation">
    <a onclick='$(".progress-bar").animate({"width": "20%"},2000);' class="nav-link active" id="home-tab" data-toggle="tab" href="#home" role="tab" aria-controls="home" aria-selected="true">Home</a>
  </li>

  <li class="nav-item" role="presentation">
    <a onclick='$(".progress-bar").stop().animate({"width": "50%"},2000);' class="nav-link" id="profile-tab" data-toggle="tab" href="#profile" role="tab" aria-controls="profile" aria-selected="false">Profile</a>
  </li>

  <li class="nav-item" role="presentation">
    <a onclick='$(".progress-bar").stop().animate({"width": "70%"},2000);' class="nav-link" id="messages-tab" data-toggle="tab" href="#messages" role="tab" aria-controls="messages" aria-selected="false" value="60">Messages</a>
  </li>

  <li class="nav-item" role="presentation">
    <a onclick='$(".progress-bar").animate({"width": "100%"},2000);' data-percent="100" class="nav-link" id="settings-tab" data-toggle="tab" href="#settings" role="tab" aria-controls="settings" aria-selected="false">Settings</a>
  </li>
</ul>

<!-- Tab panes -->
<div class="tab-content">
  <div class="tab-pane active" id="home" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="home-tab">sffs</div>
  <div class="tab-pane" id="profile" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="profile-tab">wer</div>
  <div class="tab-pane" id="messages" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="messages-tab">sdgd</div>
  <div class="tab-pane" id="settings" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="settings-tab">tjy</div>
</div>


<div class="progress">
  <div class="progress-bar" role="progressbar" style="width:0%" aria-valuenow="15" aria-valuemin="0" aria-valuemax="100" id="1"></div>
</div>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.5.3/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-ho+j7jyWK8fNQe+A12Hb8AhRq26LrZ/JpcUGGOn+Y7RsweNrtN/tE3MoK7ZeZDyx" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I figured out what mistakes I done. I solved it with jquery css width percentage for progress bar.